# Disable NOPASSWD sudo access for ubuntu user on an EC2 instance and keep it permanent

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sudo

After following this forum:
[Disable NOPASSWD sudo access for ubuntu user on an EC2 instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/615034/disable-nopasswd-sudo-access-for-ubuntu-user-on-an-ec2-instance)

I disabled sudo access for the default `ubuntu` user by changing the appropriate line in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`.

Original:

```
# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

After my change:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I also removed `ubuntu` from the `sudo` group with `sudo deluser ubuntu sudo`

I wanted to make an AMI after this change. I did, but then noticed that `ubuntu` still mysteriously had sudo privileges on new instances built from said AMI. I checked `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`. Looks like EC2 automatically appends the original setting to the end!

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) ALL

# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

The group setting was still done, however. How can I get the change to stay? I want to prevent the original setting from being reappended to that file. This seems to happen even after a regular reboot.

Here's my entire script to automate it, by the way:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# update /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users
# take away sudo for default ubuntu user
SUDOER_TMP="$(mktemp)"
sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users > ${SUDOER_TMP}
echo 'ubuntu ALL=(ALL) ALL' > "${SUDOER_TMP}"
sudo visudo -c -f ${SUDOER_TMP} && sudo cat ${SUDOER_TMP} > /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users
rm "${SUDOER_TMP}"

# remove ubuntu from sudo group
sudo deluser ubuntu sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users

```
# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

This line is writed by cloud-init. That configured on `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` .

Target line is here.

```
sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
```

comment out,

```
# sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
```

and save file.

After that, this line will not be added.